# how to deal with linkedlist?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode removeNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n) {
        ListNode countList = head;
        int length = 0;

        // get the length of list
        while(countList != null){
            length++;
            countList = countList.next;
        }
        // if it is first node from beginning just return next nodes
        if(length == n){
            return head.next;
        }
        // get the stop point
        int stop = length - n - 1;
        ListNode answer = head;

        for(int i = 0; i < stop; i++){
            answer = answer.next;
        }
        // removing the node
        answer.next = answer.next.next;      
     
        return head;
    }
}
```

I'm solving leetcode problem 19. Remove Nth Node From End of List.
I wonder how is it possible to return (original) head after I deal with the list "answer".
Is original head list being changed during I deal with the answer list?

I thought "ListNode answer = head;" line just copies the head list and answer list does not affect to head.

Comment: For reference, the problem page is https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/

Answer (score 1):

`ListNode answer = head;` does not create a copy of the head list.
Instead it just assigns reference of `head` node to `answer`. So they are both pointing to same list. That's why the original head list is being changed.